# Php simplexml Group data

Tags: php, simplexml

I'm parsing an external xml file to show how the buses go.

```
$xmlurl = 'https://api.trafiklab.se/sl/realtid/GetDpsDepartures.xml?siteId=9520&key=XXX';
$xml = simplexml_load_file($xmlurl);
```

The result is like this:

```
<buses>

<DpsBus>
<Line>Blue</Line>
<Destination>North</Destination>
<Time>5 min</Time>
<DpsBus>

<DpsBus>
<Line>Green</Line>
<Destination>East</Destination>
<Time>7 min</Time>
<DpsBus>

<DpsBus>
<Line>Blue</Line>
<Destination>North</Destination>
<Time>9 min</Time>
<DpsBus>

...

</buses>
```

Now I show the results like this:

```
$i = 0;
while ($i<100) {
echo $xml->Buses->DpsBus[$i]->Line;
echo $xml->Buses->DpsBus[$i]->Destination;
echo $xml->Buses->DpsBus[$i]->Time;
$i++;
}
```

But can I somehow group this data in a table?

So the result will be like:

Blue North | 7 min | 10 min | 25 min

Blue South | 5 min | 15 min | 25 min

Green South | 10 min | 15 min | 20 min

Any ideas?

Comment: `But can I somehow sort this in a table?` - Sort by what?

Comment: You probably mean *group*?

Comment: Yeah I meen group. I did edit my question now.

Comment: Is the data always sorted so all names of one group follow after each other?

Comment: No they're not I'm afraid :/ It's sorted by "Time"

Answer (score 0):

A side note: your XML needs fixing, you need to close `</DpsBus>`.

**Here's my shot at it:**

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($x); // assume XML in $x

// get a unique list of lines and destinations...
foreach ($xml->DpsBus as $bus) $lines[(string)$bus->Line.'|'.(string)$bus->Destination]='';
$lines = array_keys($lines);

// get the times
foreach ($lines as $l) {

    list($line,$dest)=explode('|',$l);
    $times = $xml->xpath("//DpsBus[Line='$line' and Destination='$dest']/Time");
    echo "$line $dest: ";
    foreach ($times as $time) echo "$time | ";
    echo "<br />";
}
```

**Output:**

```
Blue North: 5 min | 9 min | 
Green East: 7 min |
```

see it working: http://codepad.viper-7.com/oy7Jxc

**Explanation**

1. **create a unique list of bus-lines and destinations** (*code line 4*): Loop through the entire XML, get every line and every destination and create an associative array `$lines` with `line|destination` as key. Keys in associative arrays are unique. Using `array_keys()` in *code line 5* returns an array with all possible, unique `line|destination` combinations as values, e.g. `Blue|North`.
2. Now, **loop through `$lines` and separate `line|destination`** into `$line` and `$destination` with `explode()` (*code line 10*)
3. **select all `<Time>`-nodes of `<DpsBus>` nodes** with that specific `<line>` and `<destination>` using `xpath` (*code line 11*).
4. **output it**